# making a trial version of my app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to implement a trial for my app. i've seen how to implement it : i use

```
private static LicenseInformation _licenseInfo = new LicenseInformation();
public bool isTrial = _licenseInfo.IsTrial();
```

From what i understood, the `_licenseInfo.IsTrial()` takes info from my app to see if it is a trial version or not. Here i have a question:

1) where do i set if my  app is a trial one? when i submit the app?

When i try to purchase the app i see that you use :

```
        MarketplaceDetailTask _marketPlaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        _marketPlaceDetailTask.Show();
```

2) How does it link the trial version with the full one? is it done while adding the trial and full version to the marketplace?

and a last question :

3) when i buy and install the full version, is my trial uninstalled?

Here is where i found a good source but isn't all explained, it's just the coding about it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286402(v=VS.92).aspx#BKMK_ENABLING

(i.e.)i don't have access yet to a market place account so the upload system isn't familiar to me

Comment: I'd contact Microsoft. They **must** have this information available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) where do i set if my app is a trial one? when i submit the app?

On the marketplace submission formula. Don't ask about something you haven't tried yet.

> 2) How does it link the trial version with the full one? is it done while adding the trial and full version to the marketplace?

The Trial and the full version is the same XAP, just with a .NET Trial API limiting functionality, if the app isn't registered as purchased.

> 3) when i buy and install the full version, is my trial uninstalled?

No, again, it's the same XAP.

> i don't have access yet to a market place account so the upload system isn't familiar to me

You shouldn't ask questions when you haven't bothered to try it out first. Your questions here are silly, and any answer would be obtained by simply developing your application, and publishing it.

Asking for something you would learn regardless, is a waste of time.

Comment: the issue is that i'm on a deadline and there is a problem via Microsoft to get the account! I was just trying to find things before i have 2 days left in my deadline so i can manage problems before they appear.